# Cannot deduce return type of lambda with std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This is a strange case.

- The following code produces error when using User defined types but not when using primitives!
- It produces errors with **std::map** (also QMap) but not if replaced with **std::pair** (also QPair)!

**Why?**

I'm using **MSVC 2013**.

```
class Class {};

typedef double Type;   // This works fine
//typedef Class Type;  // This produces error

template<typename T, typename ValueFunctor>
std::map<int, typename std::result_of<ValueFunctor(T)>::type >
testFun(ValueFunctor valueFunctor)
{
    std::map<int, typename std::result_of<ValueFunctor(T)>::type > map;

    return map;
}


void test()
{
    std::map<int,Type> output = testFun<Type>(
        // The error can be removed by explicitly specifying return type
        [](const Type &pair)/*->T2*/{
            return pair;
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: Using `typedef Class type`, no issues compiling with gcc 6.3.1. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm using MSVC 2013

Comment: MSVC2013 has rather poor support for post-C++11. You need to find a better compiler. Upgrade to MSVC2015, or use gcc on Linux, with many of C++17 bits already implemented.

Comment: I'm confused what exactly I'm using from C++17. result_of is in C++11.

Comment: MSVC2013 didn't have all of C++11 either.

Comment: I got the point. So it is totally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that in MSVC 2013 and earlier, the std::result_of template is returning a `const Class` instead of just `Class`. That causes the value type of map to be non-copyable.

You can see exactly the same problem by changing `typedef double Type` to `typedef const double Type`.

If you still have to use a non C++11 compliant library, you can specify the return type of the lambda to be `Type` but that would involve a copy.

Alternatively, remove the constness but changing:
`typename std::result_of<ValueFunctor(T)>::type`

to

`typename std::remove_const<typename std::result_of<ValueFunctor(T)>::type >::type`

```
    template<typename T, typename ValueFunctor>
std::map<int, typename std::remove_const<typename std::result_of<ValueFunctor(T)>::type >::type>
    testFun(ValueFunctor valueFunctor)
{
    std::map<int, typename std::remove_const<typename std::result_of<ValueFunctor(T)>::type>::type > map;

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm wondering how did you learn about **std::recult_of is returning a `const Class`**?

Comment: that is by looking at the implementation in the xrefwrap header file.